# Elasitcsearch script query null error

Tags: elasticsearch

in ES version 5.x, I used this query and works well.

```
"bool": {
    "must": [
      {
        "script": {
          "script": {
            "inline": "params['_source']['my_field'] != null",
            "lang": "painless"
          },
```

BUT in ES version 6.2, It's error with below error message.

```
"error": {
    "root_cause": [
    {
        "type": "script_exception",
        "reason": "runtime error",
        "script_stack": [
            "params['_source']['my_field'] != null"
            ,
            " ^---- HERE"
        ],
        "script": "params['_source']['my_field'] != null",
        "lang": "painless"
    }
],
```

There is no '_source' data in params. because there is no return data with below query.

```
"inline": "params['_source'] != null",
```

How should I do with this error?

Answer (score 0):

Please, try something like this:

```
{ 
  "query" : {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "script": {
            "script": {
              "source": "(doc.containsKey('my_field') ? doc['my_field'].value : null) != null",
             "lang": "painless"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

It works on my 6.2.2 version.